# Excel Formula to Calculate Price

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am having difficulty writing an Excel formula that will count the apartment number and based on that count add up the tenants in the apartment number and arrive at a set price. $4.00 for one tenant and $2.00 for each additional. See table for reference.

| Customer Home Phone | Customer First Name | Customer Last Name | Customer DOB | Customer SSN | Customer ECOA | Joint First Name | Joint Last Name | Joint DOB | Joint SSN | Joint ECOA | Customer Address Line 2 | Customer Address Line 1 | Account Number | Customer City | Customer State | Customer ZIP | Joint Customer Same Address | Date Opened | Date Closed | Scheduled Monthly Payment | Actual Payment Amount | Date of Last Payment | Date of Account info | High/Original Credit | Account Status | Current Balance | Amount Past Due | Date of First Delinquency | Customer Residence Code | Price Column Helper | Tenant Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| (123) 456-789 | Mickey | Mouse | 2/1/1980 | 555-66-6999 | 2 | Minney | Mouse | 2/2/1989 | 555-99-8888 | 2 | 33A | 1755 Main Ave | 1234 | New York | NY | 10128 | TRUE | 1/1/2020 | 12/31/2020 | 120 | 120 | 10/5/2020 | 9/30/2022 | 5000 | 11 | 500 | 0 |  | R | $6.00 | 2 |
| (123) 456-789 | Donald | Duck | 2/2/1989 | 555-66-7000 | 2 | Daisy | Duck | 3/1/2021 | 555-22-6666 | 2 | 33A | 1755 Main Ave | 1234-A | New York | NY | 10129 | TRUE | 1/1/2020 | 12/31/2020 | 120 | 120 | 10/5/2020 | 9/30/2022 | 5000 | 11 | 500 | 0 |  | R | $6.00 | 2 |
| (123) 456-789 | Daffy | Duck | 2/2/1989 | 555-66-7001 | 1 |  |  |  |  | 1 | 33 | 1756 Main Ave | 1235 | New York | NY | 10129 | TRUE | 1/1/2020 | 12/31/2020 | 120 | 120 | 10/5/2020 | 9/30/2022 | 5000 | 11 | 500 | 0 |  | R | $4.00 | 1 |
| (123) 456-789 | Junior | Goofy | 2/2/1989 | 555-66-7002 | 2 | Goofy | Goofy | 5/1/2000 | 555-23-6565 | 2 | 32 | 1757 Main Ave | 1236 | New York | NY | 10129 | TRUE | 1/1/2020 | 12/31/2020 | 120 | 120 | 10/5/2020 | 9/30/2022 | 5000 | 11 | 500 | 0 |  | R | $6.00 | 2 |

The issue is the developer software - makes you create a new row for the 3rd & 4th tenant. So when I calculate I want row 1 to total $10 but then row 2 (3rd and 4th tenant) price to be $0 I am open to VBA, but do not know how to write it for this issue. I've tried researching and this is my last effort.

Row 1 & 2 both "Customer Address Line" is 33A and both Customer Last Name & Joint Last Name have values so the total count of tenants for 33A is 4.  The 1st tenant is charged $4.00 and each additional up to 4 is charged $2.00.  Therefore the price should be $10.00. This is the current price formula =IF(Tenant Count =1,4,(Tenant Count*2+2)) which does not work once we have a 3rd and 4th tenant.

I must keep the sheet with headers the same for the developer software it gets uploaded into. My only issue is the calculation of the price.  I've tried countif forumlas as well and it gives me the same answers as I have now.
ECOA codes will either be a 1 or 2.  Account Number if it's tenant 3 & 4 it will be like 123-A

Comment: `current price =IF(Tenant Count =1,4,4+(Tenant Count-1)*2)`

Comment: @dcromley you don't need the `IF` just `=4+(Tenant Count-1)*2` is enough because if there is only one tenant, then `(Tenant Count-1)*2` is zero. So you have `4+0` for the first.

Comment: Or `= 2+2*Tenant Count`

Comment: Both solutions provided are only taking into account each row separately. It needs to check the unit number example  33A and then count the tenants to arrive at the total price. There are 2 rows that have unit 33A and each of those rows has 2 tenants. How do you combine those into one formula. The data will change.